# How to solve error for gcloud app deploy php81

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I have this error when I go to deploy a project with php 8.1

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build 49ff6e6a-2cb1-4203-9e77-147d1f14f188 status: FAILUREfailed to build: invalid composer installer found at "https://getcomposer.org/installer": checksum for composer installer, "Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'stackdriver_debugger.so'
```

My app.yaml is:

```
runtime: php81
service: api-testing-php81

automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 4

handlers:
# Serve a directory as a static resource.
- url: /swagger
  static_dir: public/swagger

- url: /mia-mail
  static_dir: public/mia-mail

- url: /.*
  script: auto
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
```

I already specified the extension you are requesting in the error but it seems that this is failing the installation of the composer in the Cloud Build

```
===> BUILDING
Timer: Builder started at 2024-01-25T05:35:20Z
=== PHP - Runtime (google.php.runtime@0.0.2) ===
Using runtime version from GOOGLE_RUNTIME_VERSION: 8.1.26
***** CACHE MISS: "php"
Installing PHP Runtime v8.1.26.
2024/01/25 05:35:20 [DEBUG] GET https://dl.google.com/runtimes/ubuntu1804/php/php-8.1.26.tar.gz
=== PHP - Composer Install (google.php.composer-install@0.0.1) ===
***** CACHE MISS: "composer"
2024/01/25 05:35:26 [DEBUG] GET https://getcomposer.org/installer
2024/01/25 05:35:26 [DEBUG] GET https://composer.github.io/installer.sig
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
failed to build: invalid composer installer found at "https://getcomposer.org/installer": checksum for composer installer, "Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'stackdriver_debugger.so' (tried: /layers/google.php.runtime/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/stackdriver_debugger.so (/layers/google.php.runtime/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/stackdriver_debugger.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /layers/google.php.runtime/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/stackdriver_debugger.so.so (/layers/google.php.runtime/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/stackdriver_debugger.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0\ne21205b207c3ff031906575712edab6f13eb0b361f2085f1f1237b7126d785e826a450292b6cfd1d64d92e6563bbde02", does not match expected checksum of "e21205b207c3ff031906575712edab6f13eb0b361f2085f1f1237b7126d785e826a450292b6cfd1d64d92e6563bbde02"
Timer: Builder ran for 7.057739929s and ended at 2024-01-25T05:35:27Z
ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
```